# How to assign different number of columns to a div in bootstrap based on resolution range for large devices

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I am new to html,css, bootstrap.
Is there anyway we can assign different number of columns to a div based on resolution range for large device?

lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

But can I assign different number of columns for widths between 1200-1300px and 1300px-1400px  ?

Please have a look at the below image. This is how the Ui should look like. On left hand side there would be a form with four columns- 1st and 3rd column contain labels and 2nd and 4th column contain input controls.So each of these column is assigned col-lg-3. 
Now the issue is , when width is around 1250px, the left hand side form looks fine(but it needs 6 columns) but in that case grid is not able to see all the columns without horizontal scrollbar.

But if the resolution is around 1400px, then distance between labels and controls are too much and also there is a lot of empty space around the controls within left hand side form. So I was looking for a solution where I can assign the number of columns based on resolution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Bootstrap v4` to achieve it.
[image]

For more information: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You can create media queries to affect the current columns at different screen widths. Or you can create a new set of classes, like `.col-xxl-2` and give them a different percentage width, like 20% and put them in a media query targeted to the size you want. So then a div could have `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-2"></div>` and so on. I don't know if this is really necessary though, constraining it to only a 100px difference (1300-1400), because lots of computer screens go beyond that size.

**Edit** 
If you add form-inline to your form and wrap your label + input inside a form-group, it should put them on the same line with proper spacing, no matter what the size.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am not able to understand the following please guide me -

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am not able to understand the following, please guide me -  In two different forms the UI looks the same but requirement related to layout is a bit different. in One form, I want the labels to remain of fixed size but I want the input controls to expand shrink according to the width of the UI. Also I want the distance between the labels and columns to remain same in case of all resolutions and the UI should be responsive .

Comment: In second form I want the width of the form itself to be of fixed size in case of all resolutions but the width of grid to change according available width.